# How would i validate series selection in primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have scenario where i need to validate series selection of rows in datatable . I need to enable button when the rows are selected in series and disabled when the are not selected in series.

[Disable Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1l0HT.png)

[Enable Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jeays.png)

**XTML**

```
<p:dataTable id="listStackFormTable" var="stackLine"
                                scrollRows="80" scrollable="true" rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
                                value="#{stackEditBean.listStackLineForm}"
                                selection="#{stackEditBean.stackLinesSelected}"
                                sortBy="#{stackLine.serialNo}" editingRow="cell" editable="true"
                                rowKey="#{stackLine}"
                                styleClass="table-f no-h-scroll stack-Listing">
                            <p:ajax event="toggleSelect"
                                    listener="#{stackEditBean.rowSelect}"
                                    update="listStackFormTable" process="@this"></p:ajax>
                                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{stackEditBean.rowSelect}"
                                    update="listStackFormTable" process="@this" />
                                <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox"
                                    listener="#{stackEditBean.rowSelect}"
                                    update="listStackFormTable" process="@this"></p:ajax>
                                <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox"
                                    listener="#{stackEditBean.rowUnSelect}"
                                    update="listStackFormTable" process="@this"></p:ajax>
                        </p:dataTable>
```

**Java**

```
private List<StackLineForm> stackLinesSelected;
private List<StackLineForm> listStackLineForm; 



public void rowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        StackLineForm selectedRow = (StackLineForm) event.getObject();
        List<StackLineForm> list = new ArrayList<StackLineForm>();
        for (StackLineForm form : this.stackLinesSelected) {
            list.add(form);
            form.setSelectedStackLineFlag(true);
        }
        this.getDimHarvestBackingBean().setListSelectedDim(list);
        this.setStackLinesSelected(list);
    }

    public void rowUnSelect(UnselectEvent event) {
        StackLineForm selectedRow = (StackLineForm) event.getObject();
        List<StackLineForm> list = this.stackLinesSelected;
        for (StackLineForm form : this.stackLinesSelected) {
            if (selectedRow.getSaKey().equals(form.getSaKey())) {
                selectedRow.setSelectedStackLineFlag(false);
                list.remove(selectedRow);

            }
        }

        this.getDimHarvestBackingBean().setListSelectedDim(list);
        this.setStackLinesSelected(list);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put an ajax event handler for rowUnselectCheckbox and rowSelectCheckbox, and enable/disable the button in the scenario you want.

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" listener="#{bean.eventListener}" />
<p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" listener="#{bean.eventListener}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your dataTable's `selection` attribute a new list, the same type of your current list.
put 4 ajax in your dataTable with `listener` and `update`, in listeners check two lists to see if your condition is met, put it in a boolean and use it in the `disabled` attribute of your buttons. don't forget to update the buttons with client id if they're in another form.

```
                        <p:dataTable id="datalist"
                                     value="#{bean.items}" var="item"
                                     selection="#{bean.selectedItems}
                                     editable="true"
                                     editMode="cell"
                                     rowKey="#{item.id}">

                            <p:ajax event="rowSelect"   update="form:disabledBtn form:enabledBtn" listener="#{bean.setBtnDisabled()}"/>
                            <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="form:disabledBtn form:enabledBtn" listener="#{bean.setBtnDisabled()}"/>
                            <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" update="form:disabledBtn form:enabledBtn" listener="#{bean.setBtnDisabled()}"/>
                            <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" update="form:disabledBtn form:enabledBtn" listener="#{bean.setBtnDisabled()}"/>

                            <p:column selectionMode="multiple"/>
```

you can also do the boolean check, client side with javascript, I don't remember much but the general idea is like, take the dataTable dom in your ajax `oncomplete`, cycle through the children and check for elements with `selected` class and check your `boolean` in there, disable your buttons whether with css and `pointer-event` or with a `remoteCommand` to switch your `boolean`. (its the general idea, there're a little more details).